# How to read a file in Xul?

Tags: file, file-io, xul

With [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I//O#Reading_from_a_file):

```
var data = "";

Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");

NetUtil.asyncFetch(filename, function(inputStream, status) {
  if (!Components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
    error("Error reading file. Details:\n" + status);
    return;
  }

  // The file data is contained within inputStream.
  // You can read it into a string with
  data = NetUtil.readInputStreamToString(inputStream, inputStream.available());
});
```

I got:

> Error: uncaught exception:
>   [Exception... "Must have a channel and
>   a callback"  nsresult: "0x80070057
>   (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location:
>   "JS frame ::
>   chrome://myapp/content/js/utils.js
>   :: readFile :: line 234"  data: no]

line 234 refers to:

```
NetUtil.asyncFetch(filename, function(inputStream, status) {
```

And [this other example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/FileGuide/FileReading) uses IO xpcom, which is not available, where can I find it?

Is there a simple way to read a file with a single line of text in Xul?

Answer (score 2):

You need an `nsIFile` (or possibly a `nsIChannel`) as the first argument (depending on your version of Firefox).  See the [documentation for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm#asyncFetch%28%29).